# irregularity in button background selector behavior

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-drawable, android-radiobutton

In my application, I have a number of fragments.

The order of the fragments are shown in the below image:
[image]

The  App flow starts from A  and then after clicking forward button in G, it again ends up at A.

There is a RadioGroup containing 2 radio buttons in each of the Fragment F and C. For changing button colour on click, selector drawable has been implemented on those buttons. Everything works well till the flow goes from A to G. But After coming from G to A and then moving from A to F, the radio button selectors doesn't work properly and show different colours altogether. My device APK version is Android KITKAT.

Code for the Radio Button:

```
  <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/quoteEntryRadioGroupMarginTop"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:id="@+id/radioGroupQuotes"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="@dimen/quoteEntryRadioButtonPadding"
                    android:text="Field Quote Entry"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/quoteEntryTextViewTextSize"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:background="@drawable/radiobutton_left_selector"
                    android:id="@+id/radio_FieldQuoteEntry"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="@dimen/quoteEntryRadioButtonPadding"
                    android:text="New Quote Entry"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/quoteEntryTextViewTextSize"
                    android:textColor="#F4ED0B"
                    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:background="@drawable/radiobutton_right_selector"
                    android:id="@+id/radio_NewQuoteEntry"/>
            </RadioGroup>
```

Now one of the selector codes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/radiobutton_left_selected"
    android:state_checked="true" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/radiobutton_left_unselected"
    android:state_checked="false"/>
```

Now while going from A to G, this is what I am getting in E:

[image]

But then while going from G->A->B->E, this is what I am getting in E:
[image]

Can you please tell me if there is anything I am missing out?
Please do help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: dont click on 'New Quote Entry' and complete your flow A to G and and A to F, and let me know if the issue is still happening

Comment: @Rahul: By default, I have to show new Quote Entry as selected. So from the code itself, I have made setChecked(true) for that radio button

Comment: @Rahul:  even after not selecting any of the buttons, shows different colours for both conditions ( A to G and then G -> A->F)